# Why my Android Stduio application crashes from time to time without any LOG Error

Tags: android-studio, logcat

My Android Studio application crashes from time to time without  any LOG Error.
When I run it several times, sometimes the crash doesn't show up. How can I detect the Error as Logcat doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if your app crashes Errors will appear in Logcat but in case if it does not appear switch it to verbose if it still does not work try restarting the Androidstudio and see if it fixes the issue